# FFmpeg issue with aspect ratio

Tags: ffmpeg, aspect

I'm using the following command (in my android application) to overlay an image on top of a video:

```
"-i", video.mp4, "-i", image.mp4, "-filter_complex", "[0:v]pad=iw:if(lte(ih\\,iw)\\,ih\\,2trunc(iw*16/9/2)):(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v0];[1:v][v0]scale2ref[v1][v0];[v0][v1]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2[v]", "-map", "[v]", "-map", "0:a", "-c:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-r", outFPS, output.mp4
```

I implemented the above after asking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55332539/5550161) question.

---

This works perfectly fine when the video aspect ratio is `16:9`, but I have users that complain that the image is not at the correct position. I noticed that this is on devices that has a different aspect ratio, for example `13:6`.

---

Is it correct if I change the command to the following, if for example, the aspect ratio is `13:6`?

```
"-i", video.mp4, "-i", image.mp4, "-filter_complex", "[0:v]pad=iw:if(lte(ih\\,iw)\\,ih\\,2trunc(iw*13/6/2)):(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v0];[1:v][v0]scale2ref[v1][v0];[v0][v1]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2[v]", "-map", "[v]", "-map", "0:a", "-c:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-r", outFPS, output.mp4
```

I don't have a device to test with, thats why I decided to ask a question.

---

**EDIT:**

I tested with the command above using a video with the following dimensions - `1980x1020` - aspect ratio of `16:9`, then the video dimensions change to `1040x480` - aspect ratio of `13:6`.

That is exactly what I wanted, here is the issue:

If I use the video mentioned above (`1040x480` - aspect ratio of `13:6`) and I try to change the aspect ratio to `16:9`, using the first command in this question, then I get the following error:

```
[Parsed_pad_0 @ 0xeeb3f540] Input area 0:-94:480:946 not within the padded area 0:0:480:852 or zero-sized
[Parsed_pad_0 @ 0xeeb3f540] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_pad_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
```

---

**Edit2**

Running the command mentioned in the comments of the answer, this is the result.

After FFmpeg:

**Without adding `-noautorotate`**

[image]

**After adding `-noautorotate`**

[image]

---

**EDIT 3**

[Here](https://pastebin.com/7xKDxP4h) is the log without using `-noautorotate`

I used this command:

```
String[] s = {"-ss", valueLeft, "-i", mStringFilePath, "-i", drawingPath, "-filter_complex", "[0:v]scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1,pad='max(iw\\,2*trunc(ih*16/9/2))':'max(ih\\,2*trunc(ow*9/16/2))':(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v0];[1:v][v0]scale2ref[v1][v0];[v0][v1]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2,scale=-2:min(1080\\,ih)[v]", "-map", "[v]", "-map", "0:a", "-c:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-r", outFPS, path};
```

---

[Here](https://pastebin.com/FNu0tdCZ) is the log with using `-noautorotate`

I used this command:

```
String[] s = {"-ss", valueLeft,"-noautorotate", "-i", mStringFilePath, "-i", drawingPath, "-filter_complex", "[0:v]scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1,pad='max(iw\\,2*trunc(ih*16/9/2))':'max(ih\\,2*trunc(ow*9/16/2))':(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v0];[1:v][v0]scale2ref[v1][v0];[v0][v1]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2,scale=-2:min(1080\\,ih)[v]", "-map", "[v]", "-map", "0:a", "-c:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-r", outFPS, path};
```

---

Here is the links to the videos:

- [Link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/92ba9c4652aa07d209c12f59e4c7b8f220190711112651/fa969cf7ddb7ea86b9709c37bc4d298320190711112651/f2e0ac) to original video
- [Link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b7347585d7dbaf01ae0db8ae1176792f20190711113615/4c83b5d523725eb6892af386e65efa3b20190711113615/aead93) to video that doesn't use `-noautorotate`
- [Link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/11c94ac17be8c028bd614997a28e08b820190711113141/8efe951610dc9f228ecc5e3a4fa12b2b20190711113141/23e20b) to video after using `-noautorotate`

Comment: Like I said in the comment in the other Q,  change 16 and 9 to 13 and 6 in the pad filter exprs.

Comment: @Gyan Thank you for your reply, I appreciate it. Can you please have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`"[0:v]scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1,pad='max(iw\,2*trunc(ih*16/9/2))':'max(ih\,2*trunc(ow*9/16/2))':(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v0];[1:v][v0]scale2ref[v1][v0];[v0][v1]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2[v]"`

First, the scale and setsar make sure the image becomes a square-pixel input. Then the pad checks each dimension and pads to a 16:9 frame size.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96273/discussion-on-answer-by-gyan-ffmpeg-issue-with-aspect-ratio).